# React-native How to fix a view at some position by using x and y values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-animatable

I am trying to fix a view at some position that is getting from another screen. tried with transform as given below. but the x position moving wrong

```
<View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={{flex:0.85}}>
       <ImageBackground source={{uri:"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQydKa7Dh07PVap8ydkjYGRRYl1jI_YmxX2bGdB1WD1gb7XICH8wQ"}} 
       style={{width: width, height: '100%'}}>
         <Animated.View style={{position: 'absolute',  left: 0,
        top: 0,transform: [{ translateX:XYValues.x0 }, { translateY: XYValues.y0 }]
         }}><ChildComponent/></Animated.View>
    </ImageBackground>
    </View>
    </View>
```